# How to remove shadow effect in Copy/paste dialog box in android

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I wan't to remove shadow effect in PASTE dialog box in android while using Edit text. I am using android 4.1.2. I have no idea from where this shadow effect comes for native dialog box for copy/paste in android.

Any help appreciate.

Comment: can you post a picture of shadow effect you are talking..?

Comment: @sandeep please refrer this url for image: http://i39.tinypic.com/72d0kn.png

Answer (score 0):

For that button add shadowRadius attribute in xml file:
Like:

```
<Button android:shadowRadius="0">
```

Comment: user2920079 thanks for your help, but i didn't wan't to style the dialog box but wan't to remove Shadow effect. Please see image: http://i39.tinypic.com/72d0kn.png

Comment: paste is Button or any other view.

Comment: paste is not button it is the view coming when we are trying to longpress in edittext for copy/paste.